# encountering the following error in my website

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

Im getting following error frequently , i tried doing all the possible solutions and even took hosting team support but still im encountering the following error in my website

"A non-numeric value encountered in /home/hezxkegik4u2/public_html/wp-includes/ms-functions.php on line 2725"

Can someone please help me to rectify the error

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: If you add the relevant code and also sample data perhaps others might be able to help

Comment: Somewhere, some function gets a non-numeric value where it expects a numeric value.

Comment: Ok, provide the code needed from this function.php file, and we will try out best.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions to fix it

1- Login to your wordpress admin panel > General > Set a timezone then Save changes

[image]

2- Go to your hosting provider panel and change php version to a different or higher version e.g. PHP 7.4 or 8.0